# Lubuntu, set-up on virtual box

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox, lubuntu

I was wondering:if I set up Lubuntu on a virtual machine, then I've to pick the Ubuntu 32 bit set up, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu can be downloaded in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions [from here](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/).

Both versions are supported and run nicely in Virtual Box. You may even install and run a virtualized 64-bit guest operation system on a 32-bit host ([see here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests) for prerequisites and details).